# Cannot submit a transaction proposal using nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I up the network and install a chaincode and did the transaction successfully in the cli container. But I tried to do it with node SDK and it fails then I console logs the proposal response then it leaves me an error like this in the terminal.

```
[ { Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\fabric-samples\myapp\app\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\fabric-samples\myapp\app\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\fabric-samples\myapp\app\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\fabric-samples\myapp\app\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\fabric-samples\myapp\app\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:841:24)
    code: 2,
    metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
    details: 'Stream removed' } ]
Transaction proposal was bad
```

This is how my invoke.js file looks like.

```
"use strict";
/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
/*
 * Chaincode Invoke
 */

var Fabric_Client = require("fabric-client");
var path = require("path");
var util = require("util");
var os = require("os");

//
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

// setup the fabric network
var channel = fabric_client.newChannel("mychannel");
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer("grpc://localhost:7051");
channel.addPeer(peer, "Org1MSP");
var order = fabric_client.newOrderer("grpc://localhost:7050");
channel.addOrderer(order, true);

//
var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, "hfc-key-store");
console.log("Store path:" + store_path);
var tx_id = null;

// create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path })
  .then(state_store => {
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({ path: store_path });
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

    // get the enrolled user from persistence, this user will sign all requests
    return fabric_client.getUserContext("TharinduSA", true);
  })
  .then(user_from_store => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
      console.log("Successfully loaded user1 from persistence");
      member_user = user_from_store;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Failed to get user1.... run registerUser.js");
    }

    // get a transaction id object based on the current user assigned to fabric client
    tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID();
    console.log("Assigning transaction_id: ", tx_id._transaction_id);

    // createCar chaincode function - requires 5 args, ex: args: ['CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom'],
    // changeCarOwner chaincode function - requires 2 args , ex: args: ['CAR10', 'Dave'],
    // must send the proposal to endorsing peers
    var request = {
      //targets: peer,
      chaincodeId: "fabcar",
      fcn: "invoke",
      args: ["queryCar", "CAR0"],
      txId: tx_id
    };

    // send the transaction proposal to the peers
    return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request, 3000);
  })
  .then(results => {
    var proposalResponses = results[0];
    console.log(proposalResponses);
    var proposal = results[1];
    let isProposalGood = false;
    if (
      proposalResponses &&
      proposalResponses[0].response &&
      proposalResponses[0].response.status === 200
    ) {
      isProposalGood = true;
      console.log("Transaction proposal was good");
    } else {
      console.error("Transaction proposal was bad");
    }
    if (isProposalGood) {
      console.log(
        util.format(
          'Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - %s, message - "%s"',
          proposalResponses[0].response.status,
          proposalResponses[0].response.message
        )
      );

      // build up the request for the orderer to have the transaction committed
      var request = {
        proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
        proposal: proposal
      };

      // set the transaction listener and set a timeout of 30 sec
      // if the transaction did not get committed within the timeout period,
      // report a TIMEOUT status
      var transaction_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID(); //Get the transaction ID string to be used by the event processing
      var promises = [];

      var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(request);
      promises.push(sendPromise); //we want the send transaction first, so that we know where to check status

      // get an eventhub once the fabric client has a user assigned. The user
      // is required bacause the event registration must be signed
      let event_hub = fabric_client.newEventHub();
      event_hub.setPeerAddr("grpc://localhost:7053");

      // using resolve the promise so that result status may be processed
      // under the then clause rather than having the catch clause process
      // the status
      let txPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let handle = setTimeout(() => {
          event_hub.disconnect();
          resolve({ event_status: "TIMEOUT" }); //we could use reject(new Error('Trnasaction did not complete within 30 seconds'));
        }, 3000);
        event_hub.connect();
        event_hub.registerTxEvent(
          transaction_id_string,
          (tx, code) => {
            // this is the callback for transaction event status
            // first some clean up of event listener
            clearTimeout(handle);
            event_hub.unregisterTxEvent(transaction_id_string);
            event_hub.disconnect();

            // now let the application know what happened
            var return_status = {
              event_status: code,
              tx_id: transaction_id_string
            };
            if (code !== "VALID") {
              console.error("The transaction was invalid, code = " + code);
              resolve(return_status); // we could use reject(new Error('Problem with the tranaction, event status ::'+code));
            } else {
              console.log(
                "The transaction has been committed on peer " +
                  event_hub._ep._endpoint.addr
              );
              resolve(return_status);
            }
          },
          err => {
            //this is the callback if something goes wrong with the event registration or processing
            reject(new Error("There was a problem with the eventhub ::" + err));
          }
        );
      });
      promises.push(txPromise);

      return Promise.all(promises);
    } else {
      console.error(
        "Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting..."
      );
      throw new Error(
        "Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting..."
      );
    }
  })
  .then(results => {
    console.log(
      "Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed"
    );
    // check the results in the order the promises were added to the promise all list
    if (results && results[0] && results[0].status === "SUCCESS") {
      console.log("Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.");
    } else {
      console.error(
        "Failed to order the transaction. Error code: " + response.status
      );
    }

    if (results && results[1] && results[1].event_status === "VALID") {
      console.log(
        "Successfully committed the change to the ledger by the peer"
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::" +
          results[1].event_status
      );
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Failed to invoke successfully :: " + err);
  });
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?.I search in the internet and tried lots of examples but I was unable to find any suitable solution which is able to cater my requirements.If someone can do a favour to me by giving a solution to this problem It is a great plessure to me.

Comment: Have you seen the "New Programming Model" for Fabric 1.4?  The code for Invoke is much simpler.  The latest tutorial describes the new model for the Fabcar sample: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

Comment: @RThatcher I tried it but there was an issue with creating user identity with it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to the use of grpc instead od grpcs.

You can correct it by changing grpc to grpcs in your code when you use nodejs SDK. If you do this, you will find a PEM error. To correct it you should add other arguments to "newPeer(...)" function.

you can adapt this piece of code to your code where you use the "newPeer" function and if you use the newOrderer function add the changes in the same way as newPeer.

code: to add and modify:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var firstnetwork_path = path.resolve('..', '..', 'first-network');
var org1tlscacert_path = path.resolve(firstnetwork_path, 'crypto-config', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'tlsca', 'tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem');
var org1tlscacert = fs.readFileSync(org1tlscacert_path, 'utf8');

var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051', { 'ssl-target-name-override': 'peer0.org1.example.com', pem: org1tlscacert });
```